# can i delete "developer-old" folder?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, hard-drive, development

I've got a "developer-old" folder besides for my "developer" folder. "developer-old" contains "headers", "SDKs", etc folders.

It'd be nice to delete this folder bc it takes up 10GB. Can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you don't have to keep that folder according to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2780986?start=0&tstart=0

/EDIT

It's the backup of old Xcode installation.

Comment: It is of course very important not to delete if you still need to use Xcode 3.x as well as Xcode 4.x

Comment: @andynormacx nope, i deleted it and I'm still using Xcode 4.02 just fine...

Comment: Yes, because Xcode 4 is in Developer. My comment was that you need to keep it if you want to keep using Xcode 3 _and_ still use Xcode 4